# The padding property is changing all classes at the same time

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the padding of the buttons when :hover, but the three buttons change the padding at the same time when I hover over one, and I want them to do it individually.

```css
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.button {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    background-color:rgb(2, 194, 2) ;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
  
.one:hover {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons"> 
  <button class="button one"></button><a href="../new-odin-recipes/chikenpasta.html">Tomato & Basil Chiken Pasta</a></button>
    <button class="button two"><a href="../new-odin-recipes/BBQ-ribs.html">BBQ Ribs </a></button>
    <button class="button three"><a href="../new-odin-recipes/marsala.html">Chiken Marsala</a></button>
</div>
```

.one:hover does change the background color individually but the padding doesn't.  I tried removing the padding property from .buttons and .button but they still change at same time. This has to be so easy yet I'm going nuts not seeing what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: The code appears to be working as I'd expect it to.  Though note that (1) the HTML is malformed and (2) A link inside of a button is... weird.  Can you clarify specifically what problem you are observing in the demonstrated result?

Comment: I think you are not setting the CSS code properly it should be .button:hover {} and .one class is a parent container of the button

Comment: Please put your code through a validator (e.g. W3C validator). You may not have an anchor (a) element inside a button element.

Comment: I see now that putting a link inside of button element is wrong, I should be just styling the link as a button right?

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code like below. I added for the `.buttons` class `display:inline`  and i put each button in a different div which named `buttons`. For hover settings in the .css file i write for one,two, three classes one by one and also for each `button class` named like 1-2 and 3 in `css` and `html` file. I set the `position:absolute`  for button 1-2-3 and changed `margin-left` values. Additionally first buttons text is too long because of this reason i addded to `.button` class `min-hieght:50px` value and shortened the text. I hope it works for you.

```css
.buttons {
    display: inline;
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
}

.button1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(2, 194, 2) ;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 150px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(2, 194, 2) ;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.button3 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left:300px;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 150px;
    min-height:50px;
    background-color:rgb(2, 194, 2) ;
    border-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
  



.one:hover {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}

.two:hover {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}

.three:hover {
    padding: 25px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons"> 
    <button class="button1 one"><a href="../new-odin-recipes/chikenpasta.html">Tomato & Pasta</a></button>
</div> 
<div class="buttons"> 
    <button class="button2 two"><a href="../new-odin-recipes/BBQ-ribs.html">BBQ Ribs </a></button>
   </div> 
   <div class="buttons"> 
    <button class="button3 three"><a href="../new-odin-recipes/marsala.html">Chiken Marsala</a></button>
   </div>
```

Comment: thank you! I figured that using the :is() pseudo-element I can write less code also.

Answer (score 0):

add the 'align-items: start' property to your '.buttons' class selector.

```
.buttons {
    display: flex;
    align-items: start; // add this
    font-size: 24px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```